# UIPickerView in iOS, obtain text from row in different component

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uipickerview

i need to obtain the text from a specific row of the picker !!the delegate didSelect does not work, because after reloading components variable that i am getting its that information before the data was reloaded. I need to obtain the data by calling a function. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: What about the delegate `– pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:`

Comment: i need to obtain the information from a picker, this one is like a setter method,I need a getter method )))

Comment: it returns a `NSString`, it is a getter. You have to set the data in your pickerview though...

Comment: It sets the picker, but i need to obtain from the picker to an NSString !!!

Comment: something like 
NSString *temp = (NSString *)[picker ....];

Comment: how did you get data to display in your picker without using the titleForRow: delegate method?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    return [yourArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

If you want from the picker to an NSString, you just check which row is selected, and then get the string at the corresponding row-index in yourArray

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: the data from a picker with information after update, the title of the row, in case if the user makes the update of the picker and does not select the row delegate method !!!

Comment: Do you want the title to update when the array updates or what? Still don't understand. Sorry

Comment: I need to get data from the information from the label which is in the table of the picker something like that))
NSString *temp = (NSString *)[picker ....];

Comment: it doesnt matter...
I need it in that case if the user has not selected the row !!